Webhook endpoint resulting in error: FORBIDDEN You do not have access to the Apex class named
This past month I successfully set up a Webhook endpoint for Stripe in our Salesforce sandbox. I was able to test it via Postman and Stripe and everything worked just fine.
Once deployed to production, I ensured that the guest user had access to the Apex class marked @RestResource and the site is activated. But now, each time I try to access the site via Postman or directly (in Chrome), I get the following error:
<Errors>
  <Error>
    <errorCode>FORBIDDEN</errorCode>
    <message>You do not have access to the Apex class named: StripeWebhookHandler</message>
  </Error>
</Errors>

I double-checked that the Apex Class StripeWebhookHandler was enabled on the guest user of the site and that the URL was correct. I even created a Permission Set, added StripeWebhookHandler, and assigned it to the guest user.
Has anyone ever been in this situation? Is there anything I'm not thinking of. (ChatGPT and I have been having long, bonding conversations over this cluster, but nothing is working.)
Any guidance is appreciated -- especially from those who have written webhooks in Salesforce.
Again, this worked fine in the sandbox, so I know what I'm doing. The only thing that has changed recently is that a couple of managed packages have been downloaded since I deployed the webhook -- and one of them is also using an endpoint.

First (before I explain how I fixed my situation), for anyone coming to this post to resolve a similar issue, the first thing you need to do is verify that you have given your site guest user access to the @RestResource-annotated Apex class. To do this, go to Setup > Sites > [select your site] > Public Access Settings > Enabled Apex Class Access > Edit > [add your class] > Save. In the vast majority of cases, this will resolve your issue.
BUT if you find yourself facing my issue (as explained in the original post), do the following:

Check to see if there are other sites in your org, especially newer ones that were added after your site was created. Setup > Sites.
Temporarily deactivate the newer site. Check to see if your endpoint now works (chances are it will).
Reactivate the one you deactivated.
Check to see if your endpoint still works (chances are it will NOT).
If your site is once again not working, add your @RestResource-annotated Apex class to the newer site by following the directions above (Public Access Settings, etc.).
Check to see if your endpoint works again (chances are it WILL).

Obviously, this is a potential security issue. It makes no sense that a guest user for a different site (linked to a different endpoint) should affect another site. But, in my case, it does. I couldn't find any known issues related to my situation, so I'll open up a case with Salesforce.
I first discovered this situation in my sandbox and was able to replicate it in production even though the newer (problem-causing) sites were different. In the sandbox, it was a site I had created. In production, it was a site created by a managed package that was recently added.
If anyone is familiar with this issue, or believes there is a setting that will change this behavior, please let me know. Thanks!

I hope SFDC Support yields an answer as your observed behavior is quite staggering

This has worked for me recently so I don't know what specific problem you have...
You mention another endpoint being added, so worth checking that nothing has been accidentally changed for your Site. (Should not have been though as each Site in an org has it's own guest user.)
The way I would do that is:

Open the Site detail page
Click the "Public Access Settings" button
Click the "View Users" button
Click on the user (will be called "Your Site Name Site Guest User")
You can then check that the right permission set is assigned to that User
You can then click into the permission set to check that the class is still there


Thanks for taking the time to write, Keith. I followed your steps and double-checked everything and it all looked good (the same). Still getting the forbidden error. Ugh.

Yeah @Neil I thought I might be wasting your time here. There is always Salesforce support but that can take days or weeks. I'd set another Site up in production to see if the problem repeats,

I'd try a couple of other things then...

Add a debug to the GSU so you can confirm the request is hitting that
specific GSU (and that you aren't hitting a different site address in
your org- easily done!)
Add a simple VF page and controller to that
site and confirm you can access that
Use a session Id to try and access that endpoint as an authenticated user so you  can confirm the site itself is working correctly and it is definitely a perms issue


Thanks for the suggestions. I'll take a look at them.
